# Javascript map function converting values to decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array like this.

```
var elements=[5614,6619,7220,7320,7830,8220,0111,0112,0113,0142,0149]
```

Am converting every element to string so as to use with jquery autocomplete.
Am using .map function to do this.

```
elements = elements.map(String);
```

output is

```
["5614", "6619", "7220", "7320", "7830", "8220", "73", "74", "75", "98", "149"]
```

Function is taking `0111,0112,0113,0142` all these values as `Octal values` and converting them to `decimal`.

I don't want this conversation and want to preserve leading Zero also , How can I do this , please help.

Comment: You cannot preserve a leading zero on a `number` type variable.

Comment: This isn't due to the string conversion, but the fact you're defining the numerical values with leading zeroes

Comment: because, as you've pointed out, a number written like `0111` is octal notation, if your input data is a number `0111`, then you'll have a damned hard time "converting" that to the string "0111"` ... since you "have a array like this" declared with `var elements=` I would suggest you edit the code to remove leading zeros

Comment: JavaScript does not preserve the base of the number. A literal `011` will just be internally represented in IEEE 754 as a `9` and that's it.

Comment: elements.map(c=>c.toString(10))

Comment: @greentec that does exactly what OP already has.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Function is taking 0111,0112,0113,0142 all these values as Octal values and converting them to decimal.

It's not the function doing that, it's this:

```
var elements=[5614,6619,7220,7320,7830,8220,0111,0112,0113,0142,0149]
```

In loose mode, if you start a number with a `0` followed by a series of octal digits, it's octal. That's why `010 === 8` is true:

```js
console.log(010 === 8); // true
```

And heaven help us, but if you have a `0` followed by a number with non-octal decimal digits (`8` or `9`), it's decimal, which is why `011 === 09` and `9 === 09` are true:

```js
console.log(011 === 09); // true
console.log(9 === 09);   // true
```

The solution is:

1. Use strict mode (`"use strict";`). Both legacy octal literals (`010`) and legacy non-octal decimal literals (`08`) are disallowed in strict mode. (If you need to write octal, you can, with the newer `0o10` format — that's the number eight.)
2. Don't write leading zeros on numbers (with the possible exception of a `0` just prior to a `.` in a fractional number less than one)

You can't fix `elements` after the fact (because it's impossible to know, once they're numbers, which ones were incorrectly written in octal), you have to fix it at the point you're creating it, e.g.:

```
var elements=[5614,6619,7220,7320,7830,220,111,112,113,142,149]
```

Comment: Wow. An education.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder